# Embed Excel file in Delphi 5

Tags: delphi, excel, embed

I'm trying embed an Excel file into my Delphi 5 application, so I can avoid my users just deleting the file accidentally.

Using the embedded file, I create it on disk with a Save dialog, and then open it with the `Excel := CreateOleObject('Excel.Application');` method. I've seen examples on how to load a resource, using THandles, but I don't seem to get it working with `Excel.WorkBooks.Open(EmbeddedExcelFile);`.

Have you had to do something like this before? How would you do it?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Can you clarify your question?  Do you have it working now by extracting the resource from the .exe and then using CreateOleObject and Open calls to open it in Excel?  If so, why do you want to make a change.

Comment: I add data from the program, supposedly, before the user interacts with the sheet, but I didn't really know how to pass the resource to other objects. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to include the file as a resource. Say you have a `blah.xls`

Create a `blah.rc` file with the following content

```
blah RCDATA blah.xls
```

compile it with the resource compiler into `blah.res`

embed the RES file within the executable

```
{$R 'blah.res'}
```

in your application code, extract the file and run it with this code

```
procedure ExtractAndRun(resourceID:string; resourceFn:string);
 var
  resourceStream: TResourceStream;
  fileStream: TFileStream;
  tempPath: string;
  fullFileName: string;

 begin
  tempPath:=GetTempDir;
  FullFilename:=TempPath+'\'+resourceFN;
  if not FileExists(FullFilename) then
   begin
     resourceStream := TResourceStream.Create(hInstance, resourceID, RT_RCDATA);
     try
      fileStream := TFileStream.Create(FullFilename, fmCreate);
      try
       fileStream.CopyFrom(resourceStream, 0);
      finally
       fileStream.Free;
      end;
     finally
      resourceStream.Free;
     end;
   end;
  ShellExecute(0,'open', pchar(FullFilename), nil, nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
end;
```

you'll have to add ShellApi in your uses clause

maybe you'll need this GetTempDir function

```
function GetTempDir: string;
 var
  Buffer: array[0..MAX_PATH] of char;
 begin
  GetTempPath(SizeOf(Buffer) - 1, Buffer);
  result := StrPas(Buffer);
 end;
```

invoke the function like this

```
 extractAndRun('blah','blah.xls');
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I was also thinking in saving it first, but I couldn't think of a way to do it, even though I had seen examples on using Streams. Anyways, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure it will not work. You have to save the file in a temp folder, alter it and and then do whatever you want.